# Why don't the buttons change color when i click them?

Tags: python

My code isn't giving me what i want. When i click it, it turns blue until let go and then turns back to white. I want the buttons to change colour when they're clicked. So if i click it once, i want it to change to blue. And if i click it again, change from blue to red, and do this for 6 total colors (white, blue, green, red, orange, yellow)(white is the starting color).

I'm new to python coding and to be honest, it's not all my code, so i don't know what its doing. I've looked through the code to see what i can make of it.  I've also researched my question heaps but still can't find answers. This is a part of the code that i think has the problem in it. This is only the first side (of the rubik's cube) so what ever the response/answer/correction, i''l make to the 5 other sides as well...

```
def enter_yellow_face():
    top,mid,btm=[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]
    bord = [top,mid,btm]
    counter = [0, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0]

def change_color(x, b=bord):
    # seems like x is the square number out of the 9 squares
    #global counter
    r=x/3
    c=x%3
    if b[r][c] == 0:
        b[r][c]= 5
        bb[x].ss.configure(bg='white', activebackground='white')
        counter[x] = 0
        yellow_face[x] = 'w'

    elif counter[x] == 0:
        bb[x].ss.configure(bg='blue', activebackground='blue')
        counter[x] = 1
        yellow_face[x] = 'b'

    elif counter[x] == 1:
        bb[x].ss.configure(bg='red', activebackground='red')
        counter[x] = 2
        yellow_face[x] = 'r'

        ### keep following the cycle of white-yellow-red...
    elif counter[x] == 2:
        bb[x].ss.configure(bg='green', activebackground='green')
        counter[x] = 3
        yellow_face[x] = 'g'

    elif counter[x] == 3:
        bb[x].ss.configure(bg='orange', activebackground='orange')
        counter[x] = 4
        yellow_face[x] = 'o'

    elif counter[x] == 4:
        bb[x].ss.configure(bg='yellow', activebackground='yellow')
        counter[x] = 5
        yellow_face[x] = 'y'

    elif counter[x] == 5:
        bb[x].ss.configure(bg='white', activebackground='white')
        counter[x] = 0
        yellow_face[x] = 'w'

root = Tk()
root.title('Enter Yellow Face')

class Knop():
    """This is the docstring of the class"""

    def __init__(self, i, master=None):
        self.nummer = i
        self.row = i/3
        self.col = i%3
        def human_move():
            change_color(self.nummer)
        self.ss = Button(root, command=human_move, bg='yellow', activebackground='yellow', width=10, height=5)
        self.ss.grid(row=self.row, column=self.col)

        next_face = Button(root, text="Next Face",  command=root.destroy)
        next_face.grid(row=4, column=1)

bb = range(9)
for i in range(9):
    bb[i]= Knop(i, master=root)

mainloop()
```

I thought that this would create a popup window that displayed boxes that when clicked would give me different colours. Like starting with white, when i click i though it would change to blue. and if i clicked the now blue box, it would change to red. But when i run it, it actually turns blue and back to white once i let go of the click.

Comment: ***"But when i run it"***: As it stands it's **not runable**, [edit] your code to a [mcve].

Comment: I am able to run it. this is just a portion of the file...

Comment: forgot the link :) https://www.instructables.com/id/Rubiks-Cube-Solver/

Comment: What is your intention, why aren't you satisfied with [Send_Cube_State.py](https://github.com/matt2uy/Cube-Solver/blob/master/Send_Cube_State.py)

Comment: after running the code, a window pops up with 9 boxes in it(representing the 9 tiles on 1 side of a cube) but it doesn't allow me to change the colour of the boxes. when i click it is blue until i let go of the click and then it goes back to white...

Comment: Found the reason, not running for me, it's Python 2.7 code and i can run `tkinter` only with Python 3.x. After some tweaking it works for me as expected, changing color on every click. You need a **debug session**, thats out of scope at SO, `fork` the GitHub project, there i can support you.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not very good with coding stuff. whats a debug session thats out of scope at SO and whats SO?